# Why does these two arguments fetch the same value?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm learning Ajax using PHP as back-end. What I'm trying is fetching and updating the table values from database using **setTimeout** in JavaScript.

Here's my code:
(I've explained the problem below)

A. **ex1.php**

```
<?php
$a=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ndb");
$query="SELECT name from tab3";
$queryrun=mysqli_query($a, $query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script> 
var update= setTimeout(myFunc2, 4000);
function myFunc2(){
var yhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    yhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        //if(yhttp.readyState==4 && yhttp.status==200)
        };
        yhttp.open("GET", "exresponse2.php", true);
        yhttp.send();
    }
</script>
<script>
var cmp= setTimeout(cmpFunc, 100);
function cmpFunc(){
    var h="";
    var h2="";
    var cmp2= setTimeout(cmp2Func, 2000);
    function cmp2Func(){
        h= '<?php $height=mysqli_num_rows($queryrun); echo $height; ?>';
        }
    var cmp3 =setTimeout(cmp3Func, 8000);
    function cmp3Func(){
        h2= '<?php $height2=mysqli_num_rows($queryrun); echo $height2; ?>';
        if(h==h2)
            {
                alert(h+" "+h2);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Not same");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="id1" style="float: left; width: 300px">
The names are displayed below:</div>
<div id="id2" style="float: left; width: 200px">
<button onclick="myFunc2()">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

B. **exresponse.php**

```
<?php
$a=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ndb");
$query="SELECT name from tab3";
$queryrun=mysqli_query($a, $query);
$names=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryrun))
{
    $names[]= $row["name"];
}
$x="";
$count=0;
for($x=0; $x<25; $x++)
{
echo "Name: ".$names[$x];
echo "<br>";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
</head>
<title></title>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, when the page **ex1.php** is opened on browser, after 100 micro seconds **cmpFunc** executes, then after 2 seconds **cmp2Func** executes and variable **h** is assigned some value; and after 2 more seconds **myFunc2** executes (which updates table on database). After that, **cmp3Func** executes and variable **h2** is assigned value.

But every time, only if statement executes. But actually the table should be updated between **h** and **h2** are assigned values, and they should have DIFFERENT values. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The reason h and h2 are always the same is that when ex1.php is first rendered to the client, the values for the javascript are hardcoded for h and h2 at that instant in time, so they are the same every time you call that js function later.

I think a solution would involve moving the sql block for `$query="SELECT name from tab3";` to another server page that you would then hit with an ajax call inside your `cmp3Func` function.

Comment: Can I solve this problem by not changing this code much?

Comment: I think it would take me some substantial reworking, I updated my answer with a possible route to a solution.